# How to re-use grid definitions from ResourceDictionary?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I'm trying to re-use a Grid which is defined under ResourceDictionary(guiLayout.xaml)

**guiLayout.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">    
<Grid x:Key="guiLayout">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

and also I have **MainWindow.xaml**,

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <!-- I want to use ResourceDictionary definitions here-->
</Grid>
```

Is it possible to use the Grid definition from `guiLayout.xml` in `Mainwindow.xaml`?

**Edit**:

The project looks like this,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `Content` of the `Window` in XAML like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Content="{StaticResource guiLayout}">
</Window>
```

Or using element syntax:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Content>
      <StaticResource ResourceKey="guiLayout"/>
  </Window.Content>
</Window>
```

Note that without using `x:Shared` for the `Grid` saved as Resource, that `Grid` is usable only for 1 window. To use it for multiple windows, you have to add `x:Shared="false"` for the `Grid` like this:

```
<Grid x:Key="guiLayout" x:Shared="false">
   <!-- ... -->
</Grid>
```

**Update:** Try this code to import the resources:

In **App.xaml**:

```
<Application.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\guiLayout.xaml"/>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for the responce, I've tried both the approaches but I get `The Resource 'guiLayout' could not be found exception.

Comment: @San' where you imported the `guiLayout.xaml`? If possible, please post the code about doing that.

Comment: No, it's part of the main project, please see my edit section.

Comment: you are a real king.. Thanks ..:)

Comment: @San' in fact King is my English name (translated from Vietnamese) :)

Comment: Shouldn't he set `x:Shared="False"`?  According to the documentation, a value of `True` is the default, and it means the same instance is returned for each resource request (i.e., a single instance is "shared").  A value of `False` should cause the object to be recreated on each request.

Comment: @MikeStrobel yes, thanks. edited it. it's already `true` by default (which means an instance is shared for all).